# Can you blacklist a URL in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, blacklist

Context: I work with an SKD which for usage tracking performs a GET request with some basic info. One of our customers is facing some problems and although the easy way is to provide a way to disable the call and deliver a new version the Sales team wants to provide a solution they can do on their side (App) without the need to update their current version.

So the `NSMutableURLRequest` is being handled by `URLSession.shared`, my first idea was to add a delegate to the session, however this although possible won't help blacklisting the URL and it seems like the session has [several limitations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1409000-shared).

Is there a way to blacklist a URL from general use on the app?

I checked the delegate `URLSessionDelegate` however it doesn't had the capability to intercept a call before sending it. I also thought that there may be a property for the plist file which work as the opposite of `NSExceptionDomains`, but didn't found one.

Comment: how about something like this in your code, `if badurl == url { return }`

Comment: I was about to suggest `if blacklist.contains(url) { /* do something about bad request */}` but @workingdogsupportUkraine beat me to it.  However, that does depend on all network requests happening in code you control.  If they're happening in code you don't control, and your code never sees the URLs, I think you may have to resort to swizzling.

Comment: I have a [Swift package](https://github.com/chipjarred/SwizzleHelper) to help with swizzling, either to use as a starting point, or as a reference.  I've never swizzled a property setter before, but the one to target, I imagine, is `NSMutableURLRequest.url`.   Your implementation would check against the black list before forwarding to the original implementation.  What do you do if it's a blacklisted URL?  I don't know...  but setting it to an invalid URL would at least block the request.

Comment: Hopefully someone has a safer alternative to swizzling, but if you do need it, I updated my SwizzleHelper package to include swizzling property getters and setters.  Actually setters worked out of the box, I just hadn't tried it.   I had to update code to swizzle getters.  You can find an example of how to do it in the tests.